# Symfony2 Gedmo Translatable with APY DataGrid and KNP Paginator

Tags: symfony, translation, query-cache, doctrine-extensions, knppaginator

I have a few problems using Gedmo\DoctrineExtensions Translatable.

First is APY DataGrid - can't make it to show translated strings in grid on non default locale. If I use Translatable with default settings, all strings in grid are displayed in default language. If I implement Translatable in Entity and add annotations for table and other stuff, then I can see translated strings in grid, BUT after switching locales these stays the same. Seems like QueryCache is used, but can't find how to set not to use it. Here's a part for grid:

```
use APY\DataGridBundle\Grid\Source\Entity;

<...>

$source = new Entity('MainBundle:Entity');
$source->addHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker');
```

Of course it would be better to have translations without making annotations and separate entities for them.

Second problem is KNP pagination. Actually didn't dig into it, but similar problem.

The main problem is, when I run some query by translatable field of an entity. Let's say I have an Entity with name *Krepšinis* (it's basketball in Lithuanian) and I have translated this string to *Basketball*. Default language is **LT**. When in default language I perform a search, everything is ok, but if I change locale to **EN** and try searching for *basket*, it doesn't return any results and if I search for *krep*, it returns me *Basketball*. Code for search:

```
// Controller

$repository = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('MainBundle:Entity');

$query = $repository
    ->search($term)
    ->getQuery()
    ->useQueryCache(false)
    ->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker');



// Repository

public function search($query)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
    $term = $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $query . '%');
    $query = $qb->where($qb->expr()->like('t.name', $term));

    return $query;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if content is translated, you need to use query hints as you have already went through. But in order to have it cached for different locales, you need to set the locale hint to the query:

```
<?php
// hint the locale in order to make query cache id unique
$query->setHint(
    \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE,
    'en' // take locale from session or request
);
```

Which is described in the [documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#using-orm-query-hint) read it carefully.
ORM query cache is based on DQL, query parameters and query hints.